# How to do protobuf deserialization in PHP

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I am getting a response from server which I need to deserialize using protobuf. I got to know that I need to have .proto files which will contain definitions.

How can I parse the response string and create PHP objects?

Update :
I tried to use available library (http://code.google.com/p/pb4php/) but it's throwing an exception with the message 'Protofile type uint64 unknown!'. Any idea how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into code of library and found out that there is no support for uint64. Now the field which I am getting as uint64 from server is expiry time. Even if I consider 100 years as expiry, It would never get beyond int range. So I have linked uint64 to parsing of int data type and it is working fine for me.

Though it is not a good solution and completely dependent on personal usage.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download protobuf [lib for php](http://code.google.com/p/pb4php/). It comes with compiler (generator) that will generate php classes from .proto for you.

Comment: I tried to use this library but it doesn't work for me. I am getting an error 'Protofile type uint64 unknown!'. any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @CM.: I think it's worth to add that info to your question. And for the `uint64` type, you need to implement it. It's written on the homepage of that library: *"At the moment this project has an beta status. I completed the parser for the proto files and implemented Int, Enum, String and Nested Messages at the moment, for the message reading and writing. Feel free to complete the implementation."*